# Passing javascript parameter from codebehind error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use this script to call a javascript from codebehind.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Exist", "<script language='javascript'>ConfirmRedirect('" + url + "','" + msg + "');</script>", true);
```

and my javascript code is

```
function ConfirmRedirect(url,msg)
    {    

        alert(msg);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

Am getting ')' expected error.
What am missing here? If am calling javascript without paramters then it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Script tag and it will work, this worked for me:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Exist", "ConfirmRedirect('" + url + "','" + msg + "');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

View the HTML source and include it in your question/post.

You have probably just not escaped the `msg` enough. It can for example not contain single quotes `'` or line breaks.

**UPDATE**

A simple solution would be to escape all single quotes using [Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx).

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Exist", "<script language='javascript'>ConfirmRedirect('" + url + "','" + msg.Replace("'", "\'") + "');</script>", true);
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
<script language='javascript'>ConfirmRedirect('selectappraisee.aspx','Appraisal Details has been upated for ['M.P.Harimurugan'].');</script>//]]>
</script>`
This is the HTML source am getting. How should I pass the parameter?
**//]]>** why this characters coming in html source?

Comment: @itzArun That is because your `msg` string variable contains that text. You can escape them by adding a backslash in front of them like; `\'`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `msg` parameter contain symbols like the `'`

Then the code will be something like

```
<script language='javascript'>
    ConfirmRedirect('/myurl/somthing.aspx','Here's my message');
</script>
```

And there wait for the close parenthesis.

Comment: `string msg="Your Comments has been Updated"`
This is what I declared for msg.

Comment: @itzArun Then check for the same think on the url.

Comment: But am calling this script in many places. Like
`protected void RedirectMessage(string url,string msg)
    {
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Exist", "<script language='javascript'>ConfirmRedirect('" + url + "','" + msg + "');</script>", true);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your msg varriable. Use this one---

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Exist", "javascript:ConfirmRedirect('" + url + "','" + msg.Replace("'","") + "');", true);
```